# What's the link between de Bruijn-Newman constant and RH

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, constants, riemann-hypothesis

I'm not an expert in analytic number theory, but I've been curious in this last period about it. I stumbled upon de Bruijn-Newman constant during my researches on Wikipedia, where it is written that

> The constant is closely connected with Riemann's hypothesis concerning
> the zeros of the Riemann zeta-function: since the Riemann hypothesis
> is equivalent to the claim that all the zeroes of H(0, z) are real,
> the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the conjecture that $ Λ ≤ 0. $

Where

$$H(\lambda, z):=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\lambda u^{2}} \Phi(u) \cos (z u) d u$$
$$\Phi(u) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2\pi^2n^4e^{9u} - 3 \pi n^2 e^{5u} ) e^{-\pi n^2 e^{4u}}$$

- Now, I understand that explaining **exactly** how the constant is connected to RH might be kinda complicated, but what's exactly $\Lambda$?
- Why RH is equivalent to $ Λ ≤ 0 $?
- Odlyzko (2000) proved that $-2.7\cdot10^{-9}<\Lambda$ and stated that

> The new bound provides yet more evidence that the Riemann Hypothesis, if true, is just barely true.

What does he mean by "barely true"?

Thanks.

Comment: Another "danger" for the riemann hypothesis could be Lehmer's phenomenon. No idea whether it has something to do with this bound. "Barely true" just means that RH would be false if this constant would be "a bit larger" , it is apparently known to be very close to $0$ , if it is actually non-negative. If it were positive, RH would be disproven.

Comment: @Peter very interesting. Zeta function is such weird and fascinating...

Comment: MathWorld also has a short article on the constant (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/deBruijn-NewmanConstant.html) which is related to the Riemann xi-function (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Xi-Function.html).

Comment: @StevenClark oh, I see